# Use of sub report in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

CAn you tell me when you would use sub-report in Crystal Reports? I have not used them a long time.

IN the past, I would use them, if I needed to run 1 report first and then based on some output from the first report, then I need to run a sub-report. But seems this is not needed anymore.

Also would you say that  a cross tab is basically a grid?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on Subreports from Brij Mohan:

[subreport link](http://www.dotnetglobe.com/2008/02/to-subreport-or-not-to-subreport.html)

Seems to cover the key points.

As to cross tabs .... reports are a 1 dimensional list.  A cross tab is a 2 dimensional table.